# Sort values by color in Google Sheets by using google APP Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My sheet contains 4 type of rows based on cell value (Red, Orange, Yellow, and Green) and want to sort the rows based on color (so the first rows with Red color then rows with orange color then yellow and in the last green color). I have write a code to sort the range but it return rows in this order (Red, Yellow, Orange and green). How to change the sorting order by color. Cell contain values (Urgent = Red color, High= Orange color, Medium= Yellow color, and Low )

```
 function myFunction1() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve the background colors from the cells.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
  //const range = sheet.getRange(range);
  const backgrounds = range.getBackgroundObjects();
  
  // 2. Create the request body for using the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.
  const backgroundColors = Object.values(
    backgrounds.reduce((o, [a]) => {
      const rgb = a.asRgbColor();
      return Object.assign(o, {[rgb.asHexString()]: {red: rgb.getRed() / 255, green: rgb.getGreen() / 255, blue: rgb.getBlue() / 255}})
    }, {})
  );
  const startRow = range.getRow() - 1;
  const startColumn = range.getColumn() - 1;
  const srange = {
    sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
    startRowIndex: startRow,
    endRowIndex: startRow + range.getNumRows(),
    startColumnIndex: startColumn,
    endColumnIndex: startColumn + range.getNumColumns()
  };
  const requests = [
    {sortRange: {range: srange, sortSpecs: [{dimensionIndex: 0, sortOrder: "ASCENDING"}]}},
    {sortRange: {range: srange, sortSpecs: backgroundColors.map(rgb => ({backgroundColor: rgb}))}}
  ];
  
  // 3. Request to Sheets API using the request body.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

[Here is the link of my Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tGJ4pUJj42JmAMP0Ox3RDg266seW7vyrl4mgsHHH6WI/edit?usp=sharing)

Would appreciate if someone can guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I blieve your goal is as follows.

- You want to sort the background colors in order of "red", "orange", "yellow", "green" of the row.

From your showing script, I thought that you might have used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273384/7108653). If my understanding is correct, in order to achieve your goal, it is required to give your expected order of the color. If this is reflected in your showing script. please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
const backgroundColors = Object.values(
  backgrounds.reduce((o, [a]) => {
    const rgb = a.asRgbColor();
    return Object.assign(o, {[rgb.asHexString()]: {red: rgb.getRed() / 255, green: rgb.getGreen() / 255, blue: rgb.getBlue() / 255}})
  }, {})
);
```

#### To:

```
const sortColorOrder = ['#f4c7c3', '#f9cb9c', '#ffe599', '#b7e1cd']; // This means that "red", "orange", "yellow", "green" in order.
const backgroundColorObj = backgrounds.reduce((o, [a]) => {
  const rgb = a.asRgbColor();
  return Object.assign(o, { [rgb.asHexString()]: { red: rgb.getRed() / 255, green: rgb.getGreen() / 255, blue: rgb.getBlue() / 255 } })
}, {});
const backgroundColors = sortColorOrder.map(e => backgroundColorObj[e]);
```

- In this modification, your expected order of the color is given with `sortColorOrder`. The values of `['#f4c7c3', '#f9cb9c', '#ffe599', '#b7e1cd']`, which is from your sample Spreadsheet, are "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", respectively.

#### Note:

- **In this modification, from your sample Spreadsheet, `const sortColorOrder = ['#f4c7c3', '#f9cb9c', '#ffe599', '#b7e1cd'];` is used by checking each color. So, when you changed the background colors, please modify this. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- Related thread

  - [Sorting google-sheet values by cells color directly in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64263264/7108653)