# How to sort sheet by cell's background color - have the code, but don't understand the error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to finish this project but the last part is holding me up for 2 days now.  I have a Google Sheet, very simple, and I just need it to auto-sort by cell's background color.  I have 7 colors that I need in this order, and I have tried using the Sort Range Plus extension, which does work, but I can't figure out how to call it with predecided parameters whenever the sheet is edited.  So then I found an Apps Script that is supposed to do exactly what I need, and I think I enabled the Sheets API first, like the forums said to do, and I had to do this in two places, I believe, but still when I run the following code, I keep getting errors on Lines 25/26:

> Error:  Exception:  Object is not of type RgbColor.
> (anonymous)   @ SortByColor.gs:26
> (SortByColor) @ SortByColor.gs:25

I'm not sure how to fix this, as it runs and gets colors and then errors out.  I've not used javascript before, so I'm hoping someone more familiar can help me.  Maybe the issue is I enabled it incorrectly or something?  If other people have no issue with the same code, I'm thinking I may have done it wrong.  It's also my first time using Google Apps Script.

Here is the code I've been trying.  Please excuse the commented out parts - I'm using code I found in 2 different threads.

```
function SortByColor() {
    const sheetName = "Patient Progress"; // Please set the sheet name.
    //const a1Notation = "A1:A1099"; // Please set the sort range as a1Notation.

    // 1. Retrieve the background colors from the cells.
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    //const range = sheet.getRange(a1Notation);
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
    const backgrounds = range.getBackgroundObjects();

    // 2. Create the request body for using the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.
    /** 
    const startRow = range.getRow() - 1;
    const startColumn = range.getColumn() - 1;
    const srange = {
    sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
    startRowIndex: startRow,
    endRowIndex: startRow + range.getNumRows(),
    startColumnIndex: startColumn,
    endColumnIndex: startColumn + range.getNumColumns(),
    };**/

    const sortColorOrder = ['#ea9999', '#f9cb9c', '#fff2cc', 'd9ead3', '#cfe2f3', '#d9d2e9', 
    '#fffff' ]; // This means that "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", 
    "white" in order.
    const backgroundColorObj = backgrounds.reduce((o, [a]) => {
      const rgb = a.asRgbColor()
      return Object.assign(o, { [rgb.asHexString()]: { red: rgb.getRed() / 255, green: 
        rgb.getGreen() / 255, blue: rgb.getBlue() / 255 } })
      }, {});
    const backgroundColors = sortColorOrder.map(e => backgroundColorObj[e]);

    const requests = [
      {
    sortRange: {
      range: srange,
      sortSpecs: [{ dimensionIndex: 0, sortOrder: "ASCENDING" }],
      },
    },
    {
    sortRange: {
      range: srange,
       //sortSpecs: [{backgroundColor: '#d9d2e9'}, {backgroundColor: '#d9ead3'}, 
      {backgroundColor: '#fff2cc'}]
      sortSpecs: backgroundColors.map((rgb) => ({ backgroundColor: rgb })),
    },
    },
    ];

    // 3. Request to Sheets API using the request body.
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: It's very likely that the problem originates on `var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());` because the range starts in row 2 but the number of rows is larger than the available rows. If you need further help, please create a [mcve] (this means that you should include the relevant  details about your spreadsheet, remove the code that is not needed to reproduce the problem).

Comment: First, from your showing script, I thought that you might have used my answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273384 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554246 . If my understanding is correct, I deeply apologize that my answers were not useful. When I saw your script, I think that there are several modification points. One of them has already been mentioned by @Rubén 's comment. In order to confirm your script, in this case, I thought that when you provide the sample Spreadsheet, it will help to modify the script. Because, from your question, I cannot know the actual color on Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script, I thought that you might have used my answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273384 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554246, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `srange` is not declared.
- The lines of `"white" in order.` and `{backgroundColor: '#fff2cc'}]` are used as a line of a script instead of a comment.
- You set the hex color of `'#fffff'`. In this case, I think that it's `'#ffffff'`. If `'#fffff'` is used, the white background is not sorted. Please be careful this.
  About `var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());`, this has already been mentioned by Rubén's comment. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731009/how-to-sort-sheet-by-cells-background-color-have-the-code-but-dont-understa#comment126766500_71731009)

When these points are refected to the sample script, it becomes as follows.

**I cannot know the background colors of cells in your actual Spreadsheet. So in this modification, I supposes that you are using the background colors of `['#ea9999', '#f9cb9c', '#fff2cc', 'd9ead3', '#cfe2f3', '#d9d2e9', '#ffffff']` at the column "A". Please be careful this.**

#### Modified script:

Please confirm whether Sheets API has already been enabled, again.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Patient Progress"; // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve the background colors from the cells.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 1, ss.getLastColumn());
  const backgrounds = range.getBackgroundObjects();

  // 2. Create the request body for using the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.
  const sortColorOrder = ['#ea9999', '#f9cb9c', '#fff2cc', 'd9ead3', '#cfe2f3', '#d9d2e9', '#ffffff']; // This means that "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "white" in order.
  const backgroundColorObj = backgrounds.reduce((o, [a]) => {
    const rgb = a.asRgbColor();
    const hex = rgb.asHexString();
    return Object.assign(o, { [hex == "#ffffffff" ? "#ffffff" : hex]: { red: rgb.getRed() / 255, green: rgb.getGreen() / 255, blue: rgb.getBlue() / 255 } });
  }, {});
  const backgroundColors = sortColorOrder.map(e => backgroundColorObj[e] || "").filter(String);
  if (backgroundColors.length == 0) return;

  const startRow = range.getRow() - 1;
  const startColumn = range.getColumn() - 1;
  const srange = {
    sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
    startRowIndex: startRow,
    endRowIndex: startRow + range.getNumRows(),
    startColumnIndex: startColumn,
    endColumnIndex: startColumn + range.getNumColumns()
  };
  const requests = [
    { sortRange: { range: srange, sortSpecs: [{ dimensionIndex: 0, sortOrder: "ASCENDING" }] } },
    { sortRange: { range: srange, sortSpecs: backgroundColors.map(rgb => ({ backgroundColor: rgb })) } }
  ];

  // 3. Request to Sheets API using the request body.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot know the background colors in your actual Spreadsheet. So in your actual Spreadsheet, when the background colors except for the colors of `['#ea9999', '#f9cb9c', '#fff2cc', 'd9ead3', '#cfe2f3', '#d9d2e9', '#ffffff']` are used, those colors are ignored. Please be careful this.
- As an important point, when `getBackgroundObjects()` is used, I confirmed that the hex value of white background is `#ffffffff`. I'm not sure whether this is a bug or the current specification. So in this case, `#ffffffff` is modified to `#ffffff`.

#### References:

- Related thread.

  - [Sorting google-sheet values by cells color directly in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64263264/7108653)
  - [Sort values by color in Google Sheets by using google APP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71553824/7108653)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments.  I will take a look tonight and tomorrow morning and see if I can fix it.  If not, I will post tomorrow.  (I'm slammed at the office atm, so I don't have time for this.)  I really want to get this right!

Comment: @Erin Thank you for replying. If my proposed modified script was not useful, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm  thinking I did not enable the Sheets API correctly, perhaps.  I'm still getting the same error, and I created a new script and literally cut and pasted your code from above.  The error is this:  Exception: Object is not of type RgbColor.  (anonymous) @ SortByColor.gs:25  SortByColor.gs:24.                                        Up in the left panel, under Services, it does say Sheets, and I had to go somewhere else and do a second thing too, but maybe I did that incorrectly.  I'll have to investigate further there.

Comment: @Erin Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `I'm still getting the same error`, in this case, it is required to confirm your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue. Because when I tested my proposed script using a sample Spreadsheet, no error occurs. I deeply apologize that I cannot know your current Spreadsheet. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I spoke too soon!  It is working now!  Thank you so much!  Can I make this automatic onEdit?  Or is that not a possibility?  I am so new to this - I have to look up everything.

Comment: @Erin Thank you for replying. About `Can I make this automatic onEdit?`, I think that this can be achieved. But in the current stage, I think that it is a new question. So, first, how about resolving your current issue of `I'm still getting the same error`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Function assigns colors to rows randomly and the sorts the dataset based upon the color of each row.

Code:

```
function colorSort0() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 20).getValues();
  let bs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 20).getBackgrounds();
  const colors = {};
  const idx = {};
  sh.getRange("X1:X8").getBackgrounds().flat().forEach((b, i) => { colors[i] = b; idx[b] = i; });
  bs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(colors).length)];//assigned colors randomyly
    sh.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 20).setBackground(color);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();//Display all assigned colors in the spreadsheet
  });
  vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 20).getValues();
  bs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 20).getBackgrounds();//pickup assigned colors
  let A = vs.map((r, i) => {
    return { values: r, color: bs[i] };
  });
  A.sort((a, b) => {
    return idx[a.color[0]] - idx[b.color[0]];//sort by assigned color
  });
  A.forEach((e, i) => {
    sh.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, A[i].values.length).setValues([A[i].values]);
    sh.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, A[i].color.length).setBackgrounds([A[i].color]);
  })
}
```

Original  Spreadsheet before running:

[image]

After color assignment:

[image]

After color sort:

[image]