# GAS - How to sort a table by a specific cell colour, to achieve a cascading order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to run a Google App Script to "Sort columns by colour", so that all rows will cascade, in the order of a particular colour.
In the attached example, the desired "Sort-by" colour is blue.

[Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn5aW.png)
[image]

If I was to perform this manually, the steps would be:

**Step 1.** "Create filter" for the range of A3:K9. Row 3 would be the header row.

**Step 2.** Go to the right-most column (Column K), click on the header cell K3. Perform "Sort by colour", by colour blue (in this example, #4a86e8).

**Step 3.** Go to the next column (Column J), perform the same.

**Step 4.** Repeat until you reach Column B.

**Step 5.** The result would be the table shown as "After".

I have attempted to get the AI to write the script, but without success.
It seems the process of "Create filter for the table range" is skipped, therefore cells move individually - not together as rows.

I have been testing scripts on a small table, but in the actual application, the sheet is likely to have the range of A-BZ and over 1000 rows.

Any advise would be much appreciated.
Thank you for looking :-)

----- additional info ----

When I searched by my criteria as: 'Sorting values by colour in Google Sheets', all examples I found related to sorting tables with rows in solid colours. For e.g.

[Sorting google-sheet values by cells color directly in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263264/sorting-google-sheet-values-by-cells-color-directly-in-apps-script)

[How to sort sheet by cell's background color - have the code, but don't understand the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731009/how-to-sort-sheet-by-cells-background-color-have-the-code-but-dont-understa/71732653#71732653)

I am looking for a way to make row cascade according to one target colour (in my example, blue, #4a86e8). Any other colours needs to be ignored.

Also, in my example not all columns contain the target colour.
For e.g., Colum K has no blue cell.
In such case, this column (K) needs to be ignored, and sort-by-colour process needs to be repeated on the next left column (J), and all the way to the left-most of the range (B).

These were the 2 main challenges I had with examples I found.

Comment: do you have an array of colors for the sorting order?

Comment: You will have to create  a compare function for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort values by color in Google Sheets by using google APP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553824/sort-values-by-color-in-google-sheets-by-using-google-app-script)

Comment: There are several questions/answers on this subject in StackOverflow. Would you please summarise your research and explain why those questions do not meet your needs.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, thank you for your comment. I've added 'Additional info' to explain the differences between examples I found and what I am hoping to achieve. Kind regards Sam

Answer (score 0):

If the yellow is the "key color", you can achieve this with Google Script by identifying the "index" from the array or rows.

The array of 1 row will look like:

> [["#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffe599"]]

Then we use **SORT** to compare the index of KeyColor in the list of arrays.

Final Code:

```
function colors(){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");

    const vals = sheet.getRange("B2:K7").getBackgrounds();
    const keyColor = "#ffe599";

    vals.sort((a,b)=>{
      const ainds = a.indexOf(keyColor)
      const binds = b.indexOf(keyColor)
      return ainds - binds 
    })

    const sRange = sheet.getRange(2,13,vals.length,vals[0].length);
    sRange.clear()
    sRange.setBackgrounds(vals)
}
```

If these has value, you can get the values after the colors then use the Row Index to also append the value after arranging the colors.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ohmyqt,
I believe this script creates a new table right next to the original.
I am looking for a way to sort the existing table, without creating/deleting new cells.
The colour I'm looking to sort by is blue, which is not the first coloured cell in the row.
Is there a way to modify your suggestions as such?

Comment: @sam The table is just an example that's why I put it side by side for reference. You can overwrite the existing cells by adjusting the range and clearing the cell content.  It will work just fine even if the key color is blue. It will just find the first index of that color. Try changing the key color with blue.